# In SQL (Tsql) what's a good way to check mutually exclusive options are correct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**EDIT:** damien the unbeliever, my apologies, trying to be terse I omitted saying that the design of the table is not under my control; this table is a "dump" of data we receive from another vendor, and I have to convert it from their format to ours.  The reason I need a query is to find out if the data is consistent with assumptions in other parts of code.  The solutions proposed looking for length or exact match of the concatenated strings are better than my pair of queries for the problem I described.

I have a working pair of queries for my problem, but I wondered if there's something a bit prettier. Exactly one of `taxidflag1`, `taxidflag2`, `taxidflag3` should be filled in with `*` in each row. So I confirm they all have two blanks and one `*` like this.  All fields are are non nullable.

```
select * from acct where 2 <>
(case when taxidFlag1 <> '' then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when taxidFlag2 <> '' then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when taxidFlag3 <> '' then 1 else 0 end) 

select * from acct where 1 <>
(case when taxidFlag1 = '*' then 1 else 0 end) + 
(case when taxidFlag2 = '*' then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when taxidFlag3 = '*' then 1 else 0 end)
```

Comment: if they are all going to be either '*' or '', could you get away with LEN(taxidFlag1 + taxidFlag2 + taxidFlag3)?

Comment: a) could there be a Flag4 in the future? If so, it's an indicator you might want to model these in a separate table. b) Is storing an empty string really meaningful, has `NULL` been ruled out for some reason? c) Do you want to detect an issue at query-time, or are you looking for a solution that prevents broken rows from being inserted in the first place?

Comment: d) Could you not just store a (suitably constrained) integer that indicates which "flag" is set? (And pivot on retrieval, if needed)

Comment: @paul, yes that is akin to Daniel Hilgarth's proposal that I"m acceptin, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
select * from acct where taxidFlag1 + taxidFlag2 + taxidFlag3 = '*';
```

This condition is only true if two are empty (`''`) and one is a asterisk (`*`).

Comment: Are you sure you want the `&` (ie bitwise AND) there? - rather than just `+`?

Comment: Actually, I wanted `||` as this is the string concatenation in Oracle and I thought it also is the string concatenation in SQL-Server. Isn't this the case?

Comment: `|` would be bitwise OR. I don't think `||` is valid in MSSQL

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
  acct a1
where
  (select count(*) from acct unpivot (foo for taxidFlag in (taxidFlag1, taxidFlag2, taxidFlag3)) as unp where unp.row_id = a1.row_id and foo = '*') <> 1
;
```

where `row_id` is your primary key field.

Comment: +101 Thanks GSerg, this is a more generalized way to approach the class of problems that I had in mind.  Daniel and Paul more economically answered the question I asked but your query gives me a template to address a lot of similar problems that can't be transformed to string fiddling.  And I heretofor thought UNPIVOT was a pointless addition.